# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' error

Tags: php, syntax

I know this error but i can't see. please help me. I can'T solve this error

my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['giris'])){
        $papara = trim(strip_tags($_POST['paparagiris']));
            if (empty($papara) {
            echo "<center><b><font color='red'>Boş alan bırakmayınız!</font></b></center>";
            }else{
                $uyegiris = $baglanti->prepare("SELECT * FROM uyeler WHERE paparacuzdanno=? ");
                $uyegiris->execute(array($papara));
                if($uyegiris->rowCount()){
                    foreach ($uyegiris as $uyebilgi) {
                       $uyeIdsi = $uyebilgi['id'];
                       $cuzdanno   = $uyebilgi['paparacuzdanno'];
                   }
                   $_SESSION["id"] = $uyeIdsi;
                   $_SESSION['cuzdanno'] = $cuzdanno;
                }else{
                        echo "<center><font color='red'>Giriş sırasında bir hata oluştu.</font>/center>";
                }
            }
     }
```

Comment: at end of line } missing

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($papara) {
```

is missing a closing parenthesis `)`. Change it to

```
if (empty($papara)) {
```

Comment: thanks ! worked! you best :D

Comment: @TolgaUçar you could mark my answer as solution then... :-)